# A question about the Existence and uniqueness of the solution in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does the solution of the following differential equation exists in some interval       containing 0 and is the solution unique

$$(e^x\sin y)(y')^3+(e^x\cos y)y'+e^y \tan x=0,y(0)=0$$

how to find the solution of the this ODE? i have no idea to how to solve?
what kind of differential equation it is is there special method to find solution of the this type of ODE

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You use the implicit function theorem in the variable $v$ on 
$$
F(x,y,v)=(e^x\sin y)v^3+(e^x\cos y)v+e^y \tan x
$$
where $F(0,0,0)=0$, $F_v(0,0,0)=1$ for the local existence of an explicit form $y'=f(x,y)$ and then the ODE theorems for a local solution.